# Add extra fields via hook woocommerce_default_address_fields?

Tags: hook-woocommerce

We want to add extra fields to the billing and shipping addresses to the account of registered customers (users with Customer role). We also want the user to be able to edit those extra fields in their settings panel, under  ”My Account” -> ”Addresses” -> ”Edit"

I found a way to do this, namely to implement the hook woocommerce_default_address_fields, and append extra address fields there. When doing so I noticed the fields were saved to the user account, and showed up in the checkout.

So this seems to work. Now I wonder if this is the best way to add extra address fields?